# I'm unable to install libfdk-aacl on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 server

Tags: server, 18.04

I've been trying to install obs studio on my ubuntu server (18.04.1), and it requires libfdk-aacl. For some unknown reason, when I do `sudo apt-get install obs-studio` it says I "have held broken packages" and isn't installable. Any way I can install it another way?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obs-studio: Depends: libfdk-aacl (>= 0.1.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed this tutorial:

**Ubuntu Installation**

- xserver-xorg version 1.18.4 or newer is recommended to avoid potential performance issues with certain features in OBS, such as the fullscreen projector.
- FFmpeg is required. If you do not have the FFmpeg installed (if you're not sure, then you probably don't have it), you can get it with the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Then you can install OBS with the following commands, make sure you enabled the multiverse repo in Ubuntu's software center (NOTE: On newer versions of ubuntu adding a repository automatically apt updates.):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text. Post it as text.

Comment: What is `libfdk-aacl`? Why are you trying to install it? Which instruction are you trying to follow?